# В ах непонятное число записывается. Должно быть 127. в Чем проблема? Ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер

Уравнение = `(x+3*a)*(2*x-b)+d`. Окончательное значение записываю в `аx`.

.486
    .model flat, stdcall
    option casemap :none   ;

```
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
.data

A dB 4
B dB -2
D dB 7
X dB 3


.code

start:

mov al,X ; al = 3



mul A  ; ax = A*al = 4*3 = 12
add ax, 3  ; ax = 12+3 = 15;

mov bx,ax ; bx = ax; bx = 15; ; как контейнер для сохранения значения;
mov al, 2 ; al = 2;

mul X ; ax = X*al = 3*2 = 6;
sub ax, -2 ; ax = ax-(-2)=6+2=8


mul bx  ; ax = bx*ax = 15*8 = 120;

add ax, 7; ax = ax+7 = 120+7=127



end start
```

Comment: Да, дописал в начале mov ah,0/ Все равно ерунда выводится. Помогите, очень надо

Comment: вы бы дальше по коду посмотрели бы ... в mov al, 2 подозреваю та же проблема, в старшей части регистра ax что осталось ? вот явно не 0 там. вообще берите отладчик и по шагам проходите, смотрите что в регистрах

Comment: хотя не, там 0 по идее, а в итоге выполнения программы судя по всему должно получаться 135. не могу представить почему вы думаете что там будет 127. К каждой команде пишите коментарии, что должно находится в каком регистре после выполнения. так удобнее будет проверять в уме. А если хотите получить ответ тут то надо в вопросе написать почему собственно вы ожидаете получить 127, просто формулой которую собираетесь посчитать. И кстати, как вы узнаете что в AX в конце программы, если отладчиком не пользуетесь

Comment: Все расписал, уравнение уточнил, помогите отладить, не пойму в чем ошибка.

Comment: да, это я что то с расчетами намудрил. 127 должно быть. явных проблем не вижу. Что у вас в ax получается и как вы его выводите ?

Comment: Ax= 0078. Не понимаю почему так...

Comment: Можете в свой дебаггер закинуть этот код и глянуть? Ооочень выручите.

Comment: у меня ассемблера под руками нет :)

Comment: интересно. 0078 это десятичное или шестнадцетиричное ? если второе, то это 120, как будто вы смотрите в точке где add ax, 7 и эта 7 еще не прибавилась

Comment: Вооо, да, на эту сторчку смотрю)
А следущая строчка. Al = 7F = 127 в десятичной системе)
Только не пойму почему в al оно записалось)

Comment: В любом случае спасибо большое!)

Comment: ну так al это младшая часть ax. пока ax не превышает 255 al можно сказать содержит то же число